# Unpivot/Flatten pandas pivot table into one level index

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, unpivot, melt

For an analysis I start of with a dataframe, that looks like this (but is much larger):

```
      ID1        ID2           type       Number
0     IE345      E90              I           38
1     IE345      E92              E           26
2     IE345      E93              E           21
3     IE345      E95              R            9
4     IE346      E94              I           41
7     IE346      BLK              E            1
```

I would like to unpivot the following dataframe:

> ```
> Df1 = pd.pivot_table(loads, values=['Number'], 
>                        index = ['ID1', 'ID2'], 
>                        columns=['Type'], margins=True, 
>                        aggfunc=[sum] , fill_value=0)
> ```

Df1:

```
                               sum                                                    
                       Number                                                             
type                             B     D     E     I    L     R    All                         
ID1        ID2                                                                         
IE345      E90                   0     0     0    38    0     0     38    
           E92                   0     0    26     0    0     0     26    
           E93                   0     0    21     0    0     0     21    
           E95                   0     0     0     0    0     9      9    
IE346      E94                   0     0     0    41    0     0     41    
           BLK                   0     0     1     0    0     0      1
```

Into:

Df1:

```
ID1        ID2                   B     D     E     I    L     R    All                                                                         
IE345      E90                   0     0     0    38    0     0     38    
IE345      E92                   0     0    26     0    0     0     26    
IE345      E93                   0     0    21     0    0     0     21    
IE345      E95                   0     0     0     0    0     9      9    
IE346      E94                   0     0     0    41    0     0     41    
IE346      BLK                   0     0     1     0    0     0      1
```

It seems that pandas.melt is what i am looking for, but cant manage to make it work.

Afterwards I would like to add the column name of highest value of a row, but without the margins of course:

```
ID1        ID2                   B     D     E     I    L     R    All   Max                                                                        
IE345      E90                   0     0     0    38    0     0     38    I    
IE345      E92                   0     0    26     0    0     0     26    E
IE345      E93                   0     0    21     0    6     0     27    E
IE345      E95                   0     0     0     0    0     9      9    R
IE345      E94                   0     0     0    41    0     0     41    I
IE345      BLK                   0     0     1     0    1     0      2    E
```

For the max value, I used:

```
df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

but this takes the All with it unfortunately. Any ideas on how I can achieve my goal the most efficient way?

**!!!EDIT!!!!**

For the first part, I constructed a solution which returns exacte a unpivot pivot table! See here the code:

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values('Type')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Now I tried the solution of Vmg for the Max value but unfortunately it returns:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vmg has already said `idxmax` will do the trick:

```
import io
import StringIO     # for Python 2.X
import pandas as pd

data = """\
      id1        id2           type       number
0     IE345      E90              I           38
1     IE345      E92              E           26
2     IE345      E93              E           21
3     IE345      E95              R            9
4     IE346      E94              I           41
7     IE346      BLK              E            1
"""

#loads = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=0)  # for Python 3.X
loads = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=0)  # for Python 2.X

# **** interesting part starts here ****

# save all unique types, we will use it later
types = loads.type.unique()

df = pd.pivot_table(loads, values=['number'], 
                       index = ['id1', 'id2'], 
                       columns=['type'], margins=True, 
                       aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0) \
       .reset_index()

# reset column names
df.columns = [c[1] if c[1] else c[0] for c in df.columns.tolist()]

df['max'] = df[types].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
In [266]: df
Out[266]:
     id1  id2     E     I    R    All max
0  IE345  E90   0.0  38.0  0.0   38.0   I
1  IE345  E92  26.0   0.0  0.0   26.0   E
2  IE345  E93  21.0   0.0  0.0   21.0   E
3  IE345  E95   0.0   0.0  9.0    9.0   R
4  IE346  BLK   1.0   0.0  0.0    1.0   E
5  IE346  E94   0.0  41.0  0.0   41.0   I
6    All       48.0  79.0  9.0  136.0   I
```

Comment: Nice solution with the unique values out of the column! Very smart! However, it does not work yet. Types returns this: ['I' 'R' 'E' 'F' 'Y' 'G'] so I get the error: KeyError: "['I' 'R' 'E' 'F' 'Y' 'G'] not in index"

Comment: @Uis234, try to execute my script __completely__ - does it through an exception?

Comment: I tried: types = np.unique(df[['Type']]),  types = pd.unique(df.ravel()) , types = df['Type'].unique(). All return the column names without separation with ","

Comment: Hi MaxU, I tried to execute your code completely in my code, but loads = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+', index_col=0) does not execute and since i have no clue how this work, I dont know how to fix it :(

Comment: @Uis234, please post an output from: `df['Type'].unique()`, you want to do that __before__ pivoting

Comment: @Uis234, i've updated my answer - please execute it as a __whole__

Comment: I have 2.7: this is returned:NameError: global name 'StringIO' is not defined.  df['Type'].unique() = ['I' 'R' 'E' 'F' 'Y' 'G'], but i fixed that wit list() in to ['I', 'R', 'E', 'F', 'Y', 'G'], although I now use your code again so without list()

Comment: @Uis234, glad I could help :)

Comment: thx for hint how to reset column names:)

Answer (score 0):

The first transformation you describe doesn't seem to be necessary, as it seems you still want `ID1` and `ID2` to be indexes. The first representation is just how pandas shows multi indexes, without repeating the first index for every entry in the second.

Your problem at hand, of applying `idxmax` without all can be achieved with:

`proef['Dominant'] = proef.iloc[:,:-1].idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True)`

where `iloc[:,:-1]` just means you're disregarding the rightmost column.

Comment: HI Vmg, Thanks for your answer! My initial dataframe is of course different than pivot table above. Otherwise the transformation would not be neccesary. I will update the question with an intial dataframe, since I need the transformations that i did in the beginning and would like to see it transformed back as shown.